# Append Django template tag with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I want to build a menu where I can set one link highlighted using the {% block %} tag. I have something like this in my Javascript:

```
<loop>
$('#a-div').append('{% block ' + variable + ' %} <a href...</a> {% endblock %}')
<endloop>
```

In the source, this is displayed as "{% block Home %}"

How can I make JQuery not append this as a string but as a template tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. At least not without making an AJAX request to a Django template. In your case, it would be slow and make unnecessary extra requests. It's just not worth it. You can insert snippets from Django templates via jQuery by using, for example, the jQuery `load` function. But you can't replace a specific `{% block %}` tag, because by the time jQuery runs, the template has already been processed (and references to block tags removed). But this is not a situation where you should be doing that in any case.

Why don't you rather highlight the menu with a CSS class? Here is my usual solution to this problem:

1. Create a file called `base_extras.py` in one of your `templatetags` folders. If you don't have one, create one in an appropriate folder.
2. Inside `base_extras.py`, paste this code:

   ```
   from django import template
   from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

   register = template.Library()

   @register.simple_tag
   def navactive(request, urls):
       if request.path in ( reverse(url) for url in urls.split() ):
           return "active"
       return ""
   ```
3. Now, in your template, on  your menus in your base template, do something like this:

   ```
   <ul class="menu">
       <li class="home {% navactive request 'home' %}"><a href="{% url home %}">Home</a></li>
       <li class="contact {% navactive request 'contact' %}"><a href="{% url contact %}">Contact</a></li>
       <li class="signup {% navactive request 'signup' %}"><a href="{% url signup %}">Sign up</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
4. This will make that the menu where your URL currently is has the `active` class. Then, in your CSS, just add a special class for a menu item with `active` to look slightly different than the other menus.

   ```
   ul.menu li.active {background: red; color: white;}
   ```

And if you happen to need to change the active menu with jQuery, you can just remove the `active` class on all menus, and add it to the newly selected menus:

```
$('ul.menu li').removeClass('active').find('.home').addClass('active'); // for example
```

Comment: Thanks, I really liked this solution. But it doesn't really solve my problem. I should probably explained a bit better. I get the name and target of the menu link from an ajax request. so in my for loop I want to use the name of the menu link as the name of the block. I am doing this just for fun, so I am aware that this may be a very stupid thing to do.

Comment: @Pecock: That's unfortunately not possible, AFAIK. The only way would be to make a jQuery request to another Django template, and insert the returned content into the correct position by `id` or `class`, or whatever. But you won't be able to add new blocks or update old blocks in your django code with jQuery.

Comment: Well, thanks guys. I kind of found a solution, but it is bad. I just passed an "active_menu" variable from the template and stored it in a hidden field. Then compared it in the menu. I will definitely do this in a better way the next time

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that like that. The Django template tags are processed on the server side, before the page is even sent to the browser. Javascript (including jQuery) is, on the other hand, invoked in the browser, after the page has been received from the server.

What you can do is prerender the content of `{% block %}` tag to JS variable and use it in jQuery code:

```
var blockContent = "{% block Home %} ... {% endblock %}";
// ...
$("#a-div").append(blockContent);
```

If you need more than one block to choose from (as you seem to indicate in the code sample you've provided), you could resort to an array of prerendered blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a proxy view that makes what is currently your AJAX request, processes the results like the javascript would, and then returns whatever you're trying to get from the Django templating system.

Then, instead of making the AJAX call you're currently making, you call your own view instead. Django does the processing in the view like it should, you get fine-grained control over what's returned to your javascript, and it's still only one (client-side) server call.